# Preserving back buffer content after eglSwapBuffers

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, egl, double-buffering

I'm implementing in Android and native C++ a scene drawing for android using EGL 1.1.

Currently using Android's `glSurfaceView` - which allows me to draw to a back buffer which is displayed at the end of "onDrawFrame" - when the back buffer and the front buffer are swapped.

My problem is this: I need to be able to display the back buffer and continue writing as if I havn't swapped. The reason behind this demand is that the scene is **very large**, and building it each frame is not possible, neither is waiting for the end of the drawing - since the user will have to wait for too long.

In other words - I need to build the scene **incrementally**.

At a certain point during the rendering, I decide it's time and I call `eglSwapBuffers` which displays the drawn content from the back buffer, but when I continue writing obviously I'm writing to the 'former-front-buffer' which is out of sync.. (not containing the things I've drawn so far).

As far as I see my only option is to copy the back buffer before swapping. pseudo:

1. Draw to back buffer
2. **Copy** Back Buffer to temp Buffer
3. Swap
4. **Copy** temp buffer to (the new) back buffer
5. Draw more things to back buffer
6. And so on...

**Is there a way to do steps 2,4?**

- Is `glCopyPixels` useful in this case? example?
- Is `glBlitFramebuffer`?

**Or am I approaching this all wrong?**

Things I already did :

- I tried setting `EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR` to `EGL_BUFFER_PRESERVED` but it only seems to work on certain devices (as described in the [khronos notes](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/EGLTechNote0001.html)) :

  > Some surfaces allow applications to control whether or not the color buffer contents are preserved
- Re-rendering the scene in each frame - not possible. I've read many times that this is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Your general approach is correct. Using `glBlitFramebuffer()` is likely to be more helpful, as `glCopyPixels` just copies some sub-rectangle of the buffer to anouth position in the same buffer.

However, I can think of a potentially better approach, at least if [`OES_framebuffer_object`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_framebuffer_object.txt) is available:

1. draw to texture or a user-defined renderbuffer
2. render texture to BACK buffer/blit renderbuffer to BACK buffer
3. swap
4. update texture/renderbuffer
5. render texture to BACK buffer/blit renderbuffer to BACK buffer
6. swap
7. [... and so on ...]

That way you don't have a copy/update/copy/swap cycle with 2 copies per frame, but only update/copy/swap with a single extra copy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you care to elaborate a bit? What method should I use for steps 1,2? I'm very new to using gl (porting cross platform code to android.. - trying to find an alternative to ios's 'presentRenderbuffer')

Comment: @DrorFichman: Maybe [this GL wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) can help you. It explains the basics of FBOs (and that also applies to GLES, it is just a bit more limited there). So when your program starts, you create an FBO, attach a renderbuffer or a texture as the color buffer. Maybe you also need a depth buffer. For step 1, you just bind the FBO, and all rendering will be done to it. For step 2, you either use `glBlitFramebuffer`, or, if you attached a texture and not a renderbuffer, you just render a full-screen quad with that texture applied.